# python tools visual studio - step into not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I am trying to debug a scrapy project , built in Python 2.7.1 
in visual studio 2013. 
I am able to reach breakpoints, but when I do step into/ step over
the debugger seems to continue the exceution as if I did resume (F5).
I am working with standard python launcher.
Any idea how to make the step into/over functionality work?

Comment: Well to kind of answer my own question , the smartest thing to do seems to start using PyCharm instead of PTVS.

Comment: If only that was an option for me, PTVS is accessible whilst Pycharm isn't. But I'm coming up against this same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable Tools -> Options -> Python Tools -> Debugging -> Enable debugging of the Python standard library.
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/106

Answer (score 1):

workaround rather than full answer.

I encountered this problem while importing my own module which ran code (which was erroring) on import.

By setting the imported module to the startup script, I was able to step through the startup code in the module and  debug.

My best guess is that visual studio 2015 decided the imported module was a python standard library, but it really isn't viable to turn on the 'debug standard library option' as many standard library modules generate errors on import themselves.